# when i moved from FW3.5 to FW2.0 i got error

Tags: c#, frameworks

i have buield my project on VS2008 under FrameWork 3.5

now i need to move to FrameWork 2.0

when i done this, i got this error:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'TypedTableBase' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Desktop\demo2005\demo\MyDB.Designer.cs    391 68  demo

in this line:

```
 public partial class DO1TblDataTable : global::System.Data.TypedTableBase<DO1TblRow> {
```

i think that it something with the crystal-report

thank's in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Typed Dataset generator was changed in .Net 3.5 to inherit the table classes from `TypedTableBase<TRow>`.  (This adds LINQ support by implementing `IEnumerable<T>`)

You need to right-click the typed dataset and click Run Custom Tool to regenerate it using the .Net 2.0 code generator.

Comment: where i can find "Run Custom Tool"  ?

Comment: Right-click the typed dataset in Solution Explorer.

Comment: What can be done for a Website (not a Web Application Project) ? I can't find "Run Custom Tool" for that